# Android & Robotium - Testing that a fragment shows on screen

Tags: android, robotium

I have an activity from which i am invoking a fragment A and than again a fragment is introduced from from fragment after clicking a layout which is fragment B, how can i test the views of Fragment B, however easily i can do it for A.

presently what i am doing is

```
solo.clickOnView(aLayout);
solo.waitForFragmentByTag(TAGOFB, 5000);
```

And than writing test cases for B's views, but getting null with respect to them , also screen disappears after Fragment A

Comment: Are you sure fragment B appeared? You should use an assert to make sure it does: assertTrue(solo.waitForFragmentByTag(TAGOFB, 5000));

Comment: Yes B was appeared,today i removed solo.clickOnView(aLayout); and used solo.clickOnText("Text") and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Today i removed `solo.clickOnView(aLayout);` and used `solo.clickOnText("Text")` and everything was working fine, but still however i do not know why this type of behavior was there with `solo.clickOnView(aLayout);` while things are working with `solo.clickOnText("Text")`